# Responsive image or different pictures

Tags: image, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I was wondering which one is a better way to create a responsive web site with bootstrap.

```
1- Use img-responsive class for responsive images
2- Use 5 different images for different @media
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for small images, I'd use different images for different resolutions. But not using media queries in CSS - there is a [draft of a standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#embedded-content) for doing this in HTML.

This stuff is not completely implemented, but there has been some progress recently (especially in Chrome). However, there is a [JavaScript polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill) for this - I have made good experiences with it.

**Example:** It could look like this:

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 1440px)" srcset="2000px.jpg 1x, 4000px.jpg 2x">
    <source media="(min-width: 500x)" srcset="1440px.jpg 1x">
    <source media="all" srcset="480px.jpg 1x">
    <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="alternative text">
</picture>
```

The <source>-tags are processed in order, and the one with the first matching media query is used. So this would:

1. Render the image `2000px.jpg` on viewports with a width of at least 1440px and with a device-pixel-ratio of less than 2x
2. Render the image `4000px.jpg` on viewports with a width of at least 1440px and with a device-pixel-ratio of at least 2x
3. Render `1440px.jpg` on viewports that are between 480px and 1439px wide (device-pixel-ratio does not matter)
4. Render `480px.jpg` in all other circumstances, except:
5. If the picture tag is not supported by the browser, render the image `fallback.jpg`.

Using the <picture>-tag is not the only way to do stuff like this, there are more possibilities. See the draft of the standard linked above.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If you're using large images, it might be better to have different sizes since smaller sizes are better for mobile devices, especially on a mobile data connection.